# Page in React only renders elements after refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Basically I have an authentication application, where I have an authentication page where my user is sent every time the system does not recognize that he is authenticated, authentication occurs when he has a valid token registered in his localstorage with "authorization", so through "requireAuth" I created a mechanism where when a valid token is not identified in localstorage, the user is sent to the authentication page when he tries to access "/", and if he is authenticated, then he goes straight to "/ " and cannot access the auth page. This way

```
import { useContext } from "react"
import { AuthContext } from "./AuthContext"
import Authpage from "../pages/Authpage";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const RequireAuth = ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) => {
    const auth = useContext(AuthContext);

    if (!auth.user) {
      return <Navigate to="/auth" replace />;
    }
    

    return children;
}
```

As you can see, the "/" page is protected

```
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';
import Homepage from './pages/Homepage';
import Authpage from './pages/Authpage';
import Signuppage from './pages/Signuppage/Signuppage';
import { RequireAuth } from './context/RequireAuth';
import { RequireNotAuth } from './context/RequireNotAuth';
import React from 'react';
import GoogleAuthRedirect from './pages/GoogleAuthRedirect';

export function InvalidRoute() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    navigate('/');
  }, [navigate]);

  return null;
}


function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<RequireAuth><Homepage /></RequireAuth>} />
      <Route path='/auth' element={<Authpage />} />
      <Route path='/signup' element={<Signuppage />} />
      <Route path='/googleauth/:id' element={<GoogleAuthRedirect />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the part where my user gets thrown after authentication before being sent to "/"

```
import * as C from './styles';

import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useApi } from '../../hooks/useApi';
import { AuthContext } from '../../context/AuthContext';

type Props = {}

const GoogleAuthRedirect = (props: Props) => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const api = useApi();
    const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getToken = async() => {
            try {
                if (id) { 
                    const token = await api.verifyToken(id);
                    setLoading(true);                                   
                    setLoading(false);                                                    

                    if (token.success) {
                        localStorage.setItem('authorization', id);    
                        setLoading(true);                                   
                        setLoading(false);                           
                        navigate('/');
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Token não definido.");
                }            
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
        getToken();
    }, []);

  return (
    <div>
        <h3>Autenticando...</h3>
    </div>
  )
}

export default GoogleAuthRedirect;
```

The problem is that after authenticating and sending the page "/", nothing is rendered on the page and it is only rendered if I press f5 and refresh the page. Somehow I thought it could be because it is being sent before authenticating in useEffect, so I tried loading it to extend this time and without success.

ps: Homepage

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as C from './styles';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useApi } from '../../hooks/useApi';
import { AuthContext } from '../../context/AuthContext';

type Props = {}

const Homepage = (props: Props) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
  const api = useApi();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const verifyAuthTK = async () => {
      const authorization = localStorage.getItem('authorization');
      if (authorization) {
        const isAuth = await api.verifyToken(authorization);
        if (isAuth.success) {
          setLoading(false);
        } 
      }
    };
    verifyAuthTK();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Carregando...</div>;
  }


  return (
    <C.Container>
        homepage
    </C.Container>
  )
}

export default Homepage;
```

It sends me exactly to the "/" page that I would like, but the problem is that the screen is completely white and I need to press f5 to render the elements and components.